# Animation change from LinearGradientBrush to SolidColorBrush

Tags: wpf, animation, brushes

Is it possible with an animation to change the Ellipse.Fill from a LinearGradientBrush to a SolidColorBrush or change the gradientStops within the LinearGradientBrush?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use two ellipses and dynamically change their opacity.

Comment: Unfortunate how it's going to bloat the markup, but +1 for a nice lateral solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can animate the individual gradient stops of a gradient brush (and by setting them to the same color, you'd get a 'solid' color)
This is an example of animating the gradient set to the Panel.Background of some target:

```
<Storyboard>
  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="sometarget">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                         Value="Blue" />
  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
  <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).
                    (GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)"
                                Storyboard.TargetName="sometarget">
    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                         Value="Green" />
  </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```