# Animating Button.Background to a LinearGradientBrush on MouseOver

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I'm designing a custom button and want to change the its background to a `LinearGradientBrush` upon `MouseOver`. This is what I tried:

```
<UserControl Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="toBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
        <GradientStop Color="#FFC8C8C8" Offset="1"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF626161" Offset="0.599"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF787878" Offset="0.497"/>
        <GradientStop Color="#FF939393" Offset="1"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Button Content="Button" Foreground="#FFFFFEFE" Height="30" Width="120">
        <Button.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC8C8C8" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF626161" Offset="0.539"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF787878" Offset="0.467"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FF939393" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Button.Background>
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ColorAnimation 
                                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                                    AutoReverse="True"
                                                    Duration="0:0:0.25"
                                                    To="{StaticResource toBackgroundBrush}">
                                    </ColorAnimation>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

When I run the code however, I get this exception:

```
Cannot convert the value in attribute 'To' to object of type 
'System.Nullable`1[[System.Windows.Media.Color, PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]'. 
'System.Windows.Media.LinearGradientBrush' is not a valid value for property 'To'.
```

I initially attempted to animate the `MouseOver` event in Blend, but that didn't override the default template so I ended up doing in "manually" using a storyboard. I don't understand why a `LinearGradientBrush` is not a valid value for property `To` when `To` really points to the `Background` property on the button. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See if this SO question helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050032/animation-change-from-lineargradientbrush-to-solidcolorbrush

Comment: @MarkHall I tried it... doesn't change anything, the color keeps changing to the default Windows Button style.

Comment: A `Brush` is not a `Color`. Hence you can't animate the `Background` of type `Brush` with a `ColorAnimation`, and you can't assign a `Brush` to the `To` property of type `Color`.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) to find out how the `MouseOver` VisualState is implemented.

Comment: @Clemens Using `VisualStateManager` did the trick, thanks! Post your comment as an answer if you want and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example ControlTemplate in the MSDN page on [Button Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx) shows how to solve your problem by creating a Storyboard for the `MouseOver` visual state.